# react-native-maps markers in loop are not rendered

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, maps

I'm trying to learn how to create React native apps for iOS. I use `react-native-maps` package and when I render `MapView.Marker` statically, it renders to the map properly. But when I want to render array of markers, nothing happens.

```
export default (props) => {

return (
  <MapView

      initialRegion={{
        latitude: 48.99568000,
        longitude: 21.24220000,
        latitudeDelta: 0.001,
        longitudeDelta: 0.01
      }}>

    {/* this works */}
      <MapView.Marker
        coordinate={{
          latitude: 48.98975,
          longitude: 21.24697
        }}
      />

    {/* this doesn't */}
  {
    props.points.nearby.map(point => {
      <MapView.Marker
        coordinate={{
          latitude: point.lat,
          longitude: point.lng
        }}
      />
    })
  }
</MapView>
);
}
```

`props.points.nearby` array is OK, there are three items

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution:**

As I realized, *ES6 arrow functions with block bodies do not implicity return*, so I added `return` statement to my `map` callbacks and now everything works well.

Comment: I was doing this mistake as well